# Assignment problem: more agents than tasks, but tasks with multiple capacity

Tags: python, variable-assignment, or-tools, cp-sat

I've been using a pre-existing assignment tool which I use for allocating undergraduate students to  projects. I am now keen to try and build an assignment tool in python which will allow me to add and adjust constraints as we are faced with extraordinary pressures on space usage due to COVID.

The basis of the task is to place as many possible students with their favored supervisors. I have 85 students who provided a 1-to-5 rank order of preferred supervisors, which allows me to tune in a cost variable. In addition, there are 40 supervisors each with varying levels of capacity; some can take 2 students, some 3 etc, with total capacity ca 100.

I have been using Google OR-Tools, python implementation, and have attempted "Assignment with Task Sizes" strategy so far, both CP-SAT and MIP. I can produce a solution using CP-SAT for a small dummy data set, but when I use last years data with a cost matrix of size 85x40, I haven't been able to generate an assignment solution. In contrast, the MIP solver approach produces an assignment with "0 cost" and no actual assignments. I have also started to construct a minimum flow model but so far I have not been able to get the program to run on my input data.

My general question is "*what is the best general approach for such an assignment problem of more agents than tasks, but tasks with capacity to accept greater than 1 agent*."

Happy to provide what code I have if useful.
Thanks, Dave

**EDIT**
The code I have been using to attempt a CP-SAT solution is below. I initially populate a np-array of sizes defined by number of students and number of staff and populate this with the value 100. This is what I use for elements which are not a choice in the cost matrix. I have taken the student's choices ( 1-to-5) and squared to give a bit of differentiation:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    capacity=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Dave\Documents\assign_2019.xlsx', 
    index_col=0, sheet_name='capacity')
    capacity=capacity.reset_index()
    choices=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Dave\Documents\assign_2019.xlsx', 
    index_col=0, sheet_name='choices')
    choices=choices.reset_index()

    array=np.empty((len(choices), len(capacity)))
    array.fill(100)
    cost = pd.DataFrame(data=array)
    cost.index=choices['student']
    cost.columns=capacity['staff']

    choices=choices.set_index(['student'])
    for i in choices.index:
        for j in choices.columns:
             s=choices.loc[i, j]
             cost.loc[i,s]=j**2

     cost=cost.to_numpy()
     cost=cost.astype(int)

     sizes = capacity['capacity']
     sizes=sizes.to_numpy()
     sizes=sizes.astype(int)

    def main():
      model = cp_model.CpModel()
      start = time.time()

       num_workers = len(cost)
       num_tasks = len(cost[1])
       # Variables
       x = []
         for i in range(num_workers):
         t = []
         for j in range(num_tasks):
                 t.append(model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "x[%i,%i]" % (i, j)))
           x.append(t)
          x_array = [x[i][j] for i in range(num_workers) for j in 
       range(num_tasks)]

     # Constraints
        # Each staff is allocated no more than capacity.
        [model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for i in range(num_workers)) <= sizes[j])
        for j in range(num_tasks)]

         # Number of projects allocated to a student is 1.
        [model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for j in range(num_tasks)) == 1)
        for i in range(num_workers)]

        model.Minimize(sum([np.dot(x_row, cost_row) for (x_row, cost_row) in 
        zip(x, cost)]))
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        status = solver.Solve(model)

         if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
            print('Minimum cost = %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
            print()

    for i in range(num_workers):
          for j in range(num_tasks):
            if solver.Value(x[i][j]) >= 1:
              print('Worker ', i, ' assigned to task ', j, '  Cost = ', 
      cost[i][j])
           print()
           end = time.time()
           print("Time = ", round(end - start, 4), "seconds")

      if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

**EDIT 2:**
Code used for MIP solver (data input is the same as the CP-SAT attempt described above):

```
       def main():
         solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveAssignmentProblem',
                                pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

        start = time.time()

        num_workers = len(cost)
        num_tasks = len(cost[1])
         # Variables
        x = {}

      for i in range(num_workers):
           for j in range(num_tasks):
             x[i, j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x[%i,%i]' % (i, j))

         # Constraints
         # Staff can accept students up to capacity.

         for i in range(num_workers):
           solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for j in range(num_tasks)]) <= 
       sizes[j])

          # Student is allocated 1 project.

          for j in range(num_tasks):
           solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for i in range(num_workers)]) == 1)

          solver.Minimize(solver.Sum([cost[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in 
    range(num_workers)             
                                              for j in range(num_tasks)]))


          print('Minimum cost = ', solver.Objective().Value())
          print()
          for i in range(num_workers):
          for j in range(num_tasks):
            if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
              print('Worker', i,' assigned to task', j, '  Cost = ', cost[i] 
   [j])
        print()
         end = time.time()
         print("Time = ", round(end - start, 4), "seconds")
      if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The outcome of the MIP attempt is:

```
       Minimum cost =  0.0


       Time =  0.553 seconds
```

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking for advice on a new tool, or asking for code that does this. But either way, this is not an appropriate question. If you're asking for help fixing your code, you need to post the existing code and explain the problem it has.

Comment: (Described like this, it) sounds like a typical min-cost max-flow problem and ortools has even a [documentation-entry](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/assignment_min_cost_flow) for that. The good news: this can be solved efficiently (~cubic time). The bad news (compared to the more general CP-SAT/MIP approaches): it's only working for specific type of problems. Imho it should for your case, but usually informal questions like these omit some details which render some proposed concept completely infeasible later. So be warned.

Comment: This is pretty clearly an assignment problem, not a flow problem.  As described, it is a pretty clear MIP that can be solved really quickly.  The only twist is the capacity of the advisors to be assigned more than 1 student in some cases, which is a trivial constraint to add.

Comment: Have you tried enabling parallism for CP-SAT ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron Shouldn't be needed.  There's only 85x40 binary variables here.  Should solve in seconds with any reasonable solver

Comment: 2^(85*40) ?? It really depends on the problem.  Anyway you should try it.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, Yes.  You only need a binary decision variable to represent the pairing of Student with Advisor, as there are 85 students and 40 advisors, that is 85x40 = 3400 binary variables in the model, which is small.  Anyhow, I've already got a working model that solves in a second.  Unless I grossly misread the problem description--which is totally possible as stated above in comments--this is a simple assignment problem.  Happy to post it on request.  Was hoping OP would put in his code as also requested in comments, so I could refine mine .

Comment: @AirSquid, yes, I had a capacity constraint present. I had a vector which I looped through. I will post code tomorrow.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, I'm very much learning on my feet and not aware of "parallism" or seen in the documentation yet. Any pointers would be useful to try on what I had in place for my CP-SAT attempt.

Comment: *Parallelism* is maybe not the most accurate wording, but imho he is talking about [solver-param: num_search_workers](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto). Don't let it's name fool you. It's less about *splitting work* but more about trying *different portfolios* (with chances of superlinear speedup; which often is much more of a *bonus* than classic splitting). `solver = cp_model.CpSolver()` + `solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8` is how to set this and the other options (although there might already be a default of 8 at work? not sure)

Comment: Default is 1 worker.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, bearing in mind I'm actually a synthetic organic chemist, self-taught on python and at home with with 2 boys, I managed to insert the num_search_workers = 8 line into the CP-SAT code....worked a dream. Allocated all students to staff in 1.2 s on my clanky laptop....nobody got worse than their 3rd choice, which was a better outcome than what we actually assigned to this cohort last year. Thank you for the help! D

Comment: @sascha, many thanks as well for the suggestions and pointers